# fade effect in JQUERY UI calls document ready function on fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, effects

Does using fade effect as follows: `$( "#specialBox" ).toggle( "fade" )` in jQuery UI cause the page to reload when fading out?

By the way this seems to happen only when I click the button that triggers the fadeout, (rather than pressing enter).

{

```
<div id="specialBox"> //the elements who fade
  <p>Special box content ...</p> 
  <button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Close Overlay</button>
</div>



<input id = "addquery" type = "button" class = "test" value = "add query"></input> //triggering button
```

}

```
<html id= "thishtml">

    <head>

        <script  src = "jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css"></link>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "graffjavs.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>      


    </head>


    <body>

        <form id = "docy">
            <input id = "gtr" type = "text" class = "txt"></input>
            <input id = "graffbut" type = "button" class = "test" value = "test JQUERY"></input>
            <div  class = "out"   id="output">

            </div>
            <div id="overlay"></div>
<!-- End Overlay -->
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<div id="specialBox">
  <p>Special box content ...</p> 
  <button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Close Overlay</button>
</div>
            <input id = "addquery" type = "button" class = "test" value = "add query"></input>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>





function toggleOverlay(){
    var addquery = document.getElementById('addquery');
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    overlay.style.opacity = .8;
    if(addquery.isClicked == "1"){
         addquery.isClicked = "0"
         $( "#specialBox" ).effect( "fade" );
         $( "#overlay" ).effect( "fade" );
        //overlay.style.display = "none";
        //specialBox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
          addquery.isClicked = "1"
          $( "#specialBox" ).toggle( "fade" );
          $( "#overlay" ).toggle( "fade" );
        //overlay.style.display = "block";
        //specialBox.style.display = "block";
    }
    }// triggered function causing the elements to fade 




function tog()
{
    document.getElementById('addquery').isClicked = "0"; 
    $('#addquery').click(function(){toggleOverlay();});
}//function that assigns the triggered function to the button
```

Comment: Probably because the button is inside a form.

Comment: it is,  can you explain why does it happen?

Comment: The default type of a `<button>` element is `submit`, so it submits the form.

Comment: Oscar is right, your `<button>` element is a submit button because it does not specify a `type` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You button is a submit button. This is, has `type="submit"`. When you press it, the form is submitted. Change the property to `type="button"`.

Comment: Then there's something odd there. Can you post the HTML of the form where this button is placed?

Comment: sorry you are right forgot to change th fade out button thanks